# React First Item in a TextField Select does not get Selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, dropdown

I have json payload that is passed as a key value pair. I need to populate the data in a TextField select which acts as a drop down. I am able to select the first or second options in the drop down if there is two or more items in the drop down. However, when there is a single item in the drop down it does not get selected even when I click on it.

This is my code below where I set my state as I am using a functional component:

```
const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
```

This is code below that checks if the item in the TextField is clicked:

```
const handleChange = event => {
   setSelected(event.currentTarget.id);
};
```

Also this is my code below that I set the TextField with the data that I receive from the API:

```
           <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Select Department"
              margin="dense"
              name="departments"
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
              select
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-sort-props
              SelectProps={{ native: true }}
              value={selected}
              variant="outlined"
            >
              {departments.map(option => (
                <option
                  key={option.id}
                  value={option.id}
                >
                  {option.department}
                </option>
              ))}
            </TextField>
```

Kindly help me resolve this. So I can get to set the first item in the drop down even if it is the only item in the drop down.

Comment: have you tried e.target.value?

Comment: @HadiPawar I tried that as well and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had some error on your code like you used **event.currentTarget.id** but you should use **event.target.value**.

However, when there is a single item in the drop down it is not called handleChange when you click on it, because handleChange is onChange event. If you have one item, you cannot change item as there is only one, so onChange event is not fired. Instead, you can add another item like "Please select" then you can select your single item. Please check this example:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function TextFieldDDL() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
    const departments=[
        {id: -1, department: 'Please Select...'},
        {id: 1, department: 'CSE'},
        // {id: 2, department: 'BBA'},
        // {id: 3, department: 'EEE'}
    ];

    function handleChange(e){
        console.log(e.target.value, 'e');
        setSelected(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                label="Select Department"
                margin="dense"
                name="departments"
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
                select
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-sort-props
                SelectProps={{native: true}}
                value={selected}
                variant="outlined"
            >
                {departments.map(option => (
                    <option
                        key={option.id}
                        value={option.id}
                    >
                        {option.department}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </TextField>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default TextFieldDDL;
```

**Update:** Add item into the list

```
const departments = [{id: -1, department: 'Please Select...'}, ...response.data];
setDepartments(departments);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Khabir However this data is coming from an API so how do I add 'Please Select...' to the API data. as this is how I set my API data to the department. setDepartments(response.data). How do I add 'Please Select...' to this data before mapping it to the TextField.

Comment: You are welcome @JonathanLawerh, I have added just two lines of code that explains how you can add 'Please select...'

Comment: Ideally that means we can also do this setDepartments([{id: -1, department: 'Please Select...'}, ...data1.data]); And it is working now for me. Thank you.